# Cómo crear un método de extensión para la clase Color

Tags: c#

He visto que se puede hacer extensiones para diferentes clases de hecho he realizado uno para la clase string:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        //Extension para pluralizar un string
        public static string Pluralize(this string text)
        {
            string vocals = "aeiouAEIOUáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ";
            return (vocals.IndexOf(text.Last()) >= 0) ? text + "s" : text + "es";
        }
}
```

el cual convierte una palabra en singular a plural, para usarlo solo hay ke incluir el using del namespace donde esta creado esta clase y ya.

Ejemplo

```
using Badmin.Extensions;

var objeto = "manzana";
Console.WriteLine(objeto.Pluralize());
```

Comment: Hola Daniel. Y cuál es la pregunta?  no te funciona lo que has intentado? Añade informacion como el error/excepcion que te salte con ese codigo . Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los requsitos para crear un método de extensión son:

- Que el método se encuentre en una clase estática.
- Que el método sea también estático.
- Que sea accesible para el método que lo llame.
- Debe tener al menos un parámetro, y el primero será marcado con `this` y ser del tipo de la a la cual se quiere agregar el método de extensión.
- El código que lo llame debe tener un `using` al `namespace` de la clase donde está definido el método de extesión.

Por ejemplo en el caso de `Color`

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    //Extension para pluralizar un string
    public static Color AlgunaOperacionConColor(this Color color)
    {
        // Tu lógica aquí
    }
}
```

Comment: apenas publiqué la pregunta me puse a probar y llegué exactamente a tu respuesta. Gracias por todo lo que queria era hacer una extensión que al pasarle el codigo hexadecimal de un color el lo convirtiera aki lo dejo por si le interesa a alguien más: (No me cabe aki lo pondré en una respuesta)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Color FromHex(this Color color, string hexCode)
{
    //Inicializo al Color negro en caso de que introduzcan un codigo incorrecto
    color = Color.Black;
    //Si el código pasado coincide con el formato de un color en hexadecimal entonces..
    if (Regex.Match(hexCode.ToUpper(), @"^#?[A-F0-9]{6}$").Success)
    {
        //Almaceno en val el código sin el caracter #
        var val = hexCode.Trim('#');
        //Convierto a entero las dos primeras letras del código perteneciente al valor de R (red) del color
        var r = Convert.ToInt32(val.Substring(0, 2), 16);
        //Convierto a entero la 3ra y cuarta letra del código perteneciente al valor de G (green) del color
        var g = Convert.ToInt32(val.Substring(2, 2), 16);
        //Convierto a entero la 5ra y última letra del código perteneciente al valor de B (blue) del color
        var b = Convert.ToInt32(val.Substring(4, 2), 16);
        //Le asigno a color una nueva instancia ya con los valores convertidos
        color = Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: No se como especificar para que tome el formato de c#, estuve leyendo y encontre que tenia que poner al comienzo una cabecera como esta: <!-- language: lang-js --> en mi caso me imaginaba que fuera c#, csharp, o cs pero nada.

Comment: Solo necesitas comenzar cada linea con 4 espacios en blanco. El lenguaje generalmente es autodetectado correctamente. Podrías ponerle un poco mas de explicación a tu código o por ahí aparecerá alguien votando negativamente tu respuesta o reportándolo como de baja calidad.

Comment: Gracias por todo, soy nuevo aki.